# FastAPI variable into Jinja2

Tags: nginx, jinja2, fastapi

The FastAPI application is running on a server and returning some jinja2 templates. The static files are sitting on another server and an nginx serves those. How do I **neatly** pass the static files url to the jinja2 templates?

Answer (score 0):

There's different approaches to this, but a CDN/static url prefix is usually environment dependent, so it makes sense to declare a env/config variable for this and pass it to the template. The latter can be done using dependency injection or argument passing, or be some global context tag, more on these options can be found in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/settings/)